# how to a get a specific string in a file

Tags: java

here in my file content 2017-05-05 08:24:46 to 2017-05-05 08:24:55, now i need to print from-2017-05-05 08:24:49 to -2017-05-05 08:24:52 contents in between the date. can you suggest someother method other than this.

1.file content:

```
[2017-05-05 08:24:46]contents is [ [pool-80 
 thread.PaseInterceptorChain... zhjkhzjh]nkshxkjghsjkgjskgxsjgxjsagxhujgsxhjsxghjvasxhasvxhjvsaxhvshjxvhjvhxjvhsvxhj
[2017-05-05 08:24:49]contents is [ [pool-80-thread-1] xhggajgzjh
 icationExceptionOutInterceptor... nvsjhkslkxlxskl]jsahxjahx
[2017-05-05 08:24:49]contents is [ [pool-78-thread-1.. ]
[2017-05-05 08:24:52]contents is [ [pool-78-thread-1... ]
[2017-05-05 08:24:52]contents is [ [pool-78-thread-1... {... = 
 contents inside}]
[2017-05-05 08:24:55]contents is [ [pool-78-thread-1... {... = 
 contents inside}]
```

2.this is my code:

```
public class MeteringlogBean implements Serializable 
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Date date10;
private Date date11;
private String d;
private String d1;
private String s;
private String text;
private FileWriter fw;
private BufferedWriter bw;
private String Fn = "C:/Users/swetha.papireddy/Documents/new/filename.txt";
public Date getDate11() {
return date11;
}
public void setDate11(Date date11) {
this.date11 = date11;
}
private String environment;
public String getEnvironment() {
return environment;
}
public void setEnvironment(String environment) {
this.environment = environment;
}
public Date getDate10() {
return date10;
}
public void setDate10(Date date10) {
this.date10 = date10;
}

public void save() throws IOException, NullPointerException {
try {
    File file = new File(getEnvironment() + "/ischange.log");
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        stringBuilder.append(line);
        stringBuilder.append("\n");
    }
    fileReader.close();
    System.out.println("Contents of file:");
    s = stringBuilder.toString();
    System.out.println(s);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

d = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(date10);
System.out.println("date:-" + d);
d1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(date11);
System.out.println("date:-" + d1);

fw = new FileWriter(Fn);
bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
bw.write(s);
bw.close();

File file = new File(Fn);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];
fis.read(bytes);
fis.close();

String text = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
String str1 = new String(d);
String str2 = new String(d1);
System.out.println(text.substring(text.indexOf(str1),
        text.lastIndexOf(str2)));
}
```

3.my actual output is:

```
 [2017-05-05 08:24:49]contents is [ [pool-80-thread-1] xhggajgzjh
icationExceptionOutInterceptor... nvsjhkslkxlxskl]jsahxjahx
[2017-05-05 08:24:49]contents is [ [pool-78-thread-1.. ]
[2017-05-05 08:24:52]contents is [ [pool-78-thread-1... ]
```

now i need to get two [2017-05-05 08:24:52]

4.output should be:

```
[2017-05-05 08:24:49]contents is [ [pool-80-thread-1] xhggajgzjh
icationExceptionOutInterceptor... nvsjhkslkxlxskl]jsahxjahx
[2017-05-05 08:24:49]contents is [ [pool-78-thread-1.. ]
[2017-05-05 08:24:52]contents is [ [pool-78-thread-1... ]
[2017-05-05 08:24:52]contents is [ [pool-78-thread-1... {... = 
 contents inside}]
```

Comment: Please properly format the example code and use meaningful variable names. As it is, this code is too hard to read.

Comment: Have two booleans that indicates that if first string found, and second string found `if firsStringFound && secondStringFound && dateString not equals to secondString then break`

Answer (score 2):

You can use String.contains(your search String) or String.endsWith() or String.startsWith()
or use a logic something like

```
while((currentLine = scanner.readLine()) != null)
{
    if(currentLine.indexOf("Your String"))
    {
         //Do task
         passedLine = true;
    }
    if(passedLine)
    {
       //Do other task after passing the line.
    }
    lineNumber++;
}
```

Comment: where to use this?

Answer (score 1):

Read the file and store the result in String builder.

```
public static String getInputString(String filepath)  throws IOException {
        RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile
                (filepath, "r");
        FileChannel channel = randomAccessFile.getChannel();
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);      //Reading the file in chunk of 1024 bytes[1KB]
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
        while(channel.read(buffer) > 0)
        {
            buffer.flip();                                  //Ready for get ,put operation
            for (int i = 0; i < buffer.limit(); i++)
            {
                sb.append((char)buffer.get());              //Reading every character and appending to Stringbuilder            
            }
            buffer.clear();
        }        
        channel.close();
        randomAccessFile.close();
        return sb.toString(); 
    }
```

Use regex to find the log text between date ::

```
private  HashMap<String, List<String>> parsedMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
public  HashMap<String, List<String>> getValues(String inputSTring) {
        String regex = "(?=((("Start Date")(.*?|\n.*?)("End Date"))))";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputSTring);

        while(matcher.find()) {
            String key = matcher.group(3);
            String value = matcher.group(4);            

            System.out.println(key + " => " + value);
            List<String>contentsList = parsedMap.get(key);
            if(contentsList == null) {
                contentsList = new ArrayList<String>();
                parsedMap.put(key, contentsList);
            }
            contentsList.add(value);
        }
        return parsedMap;       
    }
```

Then Fetch the value from HashmMap and create new output String.

Comment: its not working for me.. can you give someother method

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the logic to get the next datetime value and use it to get till the previous value.

Example :
currently you are getting the logs till  [2017-05-05 08:24:52]. Before specifying the last index of this String, try to identify the next immediate datetime value after " [2017-05-05 08:24:52]". 
Use String.contains to get it.

Login to get the last line :

```
Current datetime = "2017-05-05 08:24:52";
boolean nextValueFound;
while(!nextValueFound){
Date newDate = calender.add(Date, 1); // this will add seconds (not exactly. please check)
//convert the date to String
dateStringtobeCheckedinText = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(date11);
if(text.contains(dateStringtobeCheckedinText)){
    nextValueFound = true;
}
}

// your required text:
System.out.println(text.substring(text.indexOf(str1),
        text.indexOf(dateStringtobeCheckedinText )));
```

Comment: but here im not giving specific current datetime , i can select any date. date10 is for from date and date11 is for To date

Comment: you need to search for start of date10 to end of date 11 line. Since you are trying to get is as substring, you need to search between first occurrence of date10  --- to --- first occurrence of the date value next to date11 that is present in the String that you search. So before applying substring, get the next date value present in the log(StringText)

Comment: yes, in date11 its stops as soon as it finds the date, but i need to print all the occurance of the date11. for eg:[2017-05-05 08:24:49]
[2017-05-05 08:24:49]
[2017-05-05 08:24:52]--upto this it will print 
[2017-05-05 08:24:52] -- i need this line r date too

Comment: Date newDate = calender.add(Date, 1); im getting error in this line

Comment: 'Date date = date10;
   Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
   cal.setTime(date);
   cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 1);
   nextdate = d1.format(cal.getTime());
'

Now search for nextdate in your string. Keep getting the nextadte untill you find an occurance in your string. If none is found, then the log must end with your date, so you can take til end of file. Hope this helps!

Comment: boolean nextValueFound = false;
  while(!nextValueFound){
  Date date = date10;
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  cal.setTime(date);
  cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 1); 
  //date = d1.format(cal.getTime());
  d1= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(date10);
  if(text.contains(d1)){
      nextValueFound = true;
  }
  }

 
  System.out.println(text.substring(text.indexOf(str1),
          text.indexOf(d1 )));

Comment: What is the output you are getting ?

Comment: its not printing anything

Comment: try the below code
''

String str1 = input_log_start_Date;
String str2 = input_log_end_date;
String str3 = final_end_Date;
boolean endValuefound= false;
while(endValuefound){
Date date = input_end_date;
Calender cal  = Calender.getInstance();
cal.add(Caldner.SECOND,1);
date = cal.getTime();
str3 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(date);
if(text.contains(str3)){
endValuefound=true;
}
}
if(endValuefound){
System.out.println(text.substring(text.indexOf(str1), text.indexOf(str3)));
}
else{
System.out.println(text.subString(text.indexOf(str1)));
}''

Comment: unable to format the code above. sorry. Logic is to find the next date value in the log and print till the start of it which will suit your requirement.
to get and check for next date in the text, try to increment the end date that is inputed and verify in text if the next date is found.

the above code will run infinite if it couldnt find the next date. We need to have some condition to stop the loop.